# How to update recently entered element in std::vector<pair<int, int>>?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++17, stdvector, std-pair

How can one update the value for pairs in any vector class of pair type?

Example :

```
V.push_back(make_pair(1, 3));
```

If I wish to update `3` to say `5` or something, how do I achieve that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that you want to update the **last** `std::pair` input just after inserting to the `std::vector<std::pair<int, int>>`.

In **[c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17)** you can make use of second overload of **[`std::vector::emplace_back`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back)**, which returns a *reference* to the element inserted:

```
#include <vector>

std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> vec;
auto &pair = vec.emplace_back(1, 3); // construct in-place and get the reference to the inserted element
pair.second = 5;                     // change the value directly like this
```

---

**Update:**

In **[c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11)**, the same can be achieved by the **[`std::vector::insert`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/insert)** member, which returns *iterator* pointing to the inserted element.

```
#include <vector>

std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> vec;
// insert the element to vec and get the iterator pointing to the element
const auto iter = vec.insert(vec.cend(), { 1, 3 });
iter->second = 5; // change the value
```

Answer (score 5):

You access a value within your `vector` and just set the values you want to change. Assuming you have mutable access to your `vector`.

```
V.back().first = 1;
V.back().second = 2;
```

If you know the index of the item within the `vector`, you can use `operator[]` or `at` to get a reference to the item. You can also copy a new value into the same position.

```
V[0] = std::make_pair(3, 5);
```

Comment: Would probably suggest using `back()` in the example given that the OP _sort of_ suggests it's the most recently `push_back()`'d element they want to modify ... but this is really nitpicking

Comment: Oh man you really are nit-picking @LightnessRacesinOrbit ;-).

Answer (score 2):

If `i` is the index in the `std::vector` containing the `std::pair` you wish to update:

```
vec.at(i).second = 5;
```

Also note that `std::pair` overrides the `=` operator so you can assign the entire pair again with:

```
vec.at(i) = std::make_pair(val1, val2);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to modify all pairs in the vector `V`, iterate with a `for` loop:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < V.size(); i++)
 {  
     V[i].first = // some value;
     V[i].second = // some value;
 }
```